# Question about Map and Total

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Suppose I have a list and I want to generate a new list, such that

$$ NewList[index] = \sum_{index \neq j}^{NumOfElts} \frac {1}{ \lvert OldList[index]-OldList[j] \rvert ^2 } $$

Can I do it using Map and Total on $OldList$?

#### Edit

Given `OldList = {a, b, c}`, I want `NewList` to be

> ```
> {1/Abs[a - b]^2 + 1/Abs[a - c]^2,
>  1/Abs[-a + b]^2 + 1/Abs[b - c]^2, 
>  1/Abs[-a + c]^2 + 1/Abs[-b + c]^2}
> ```

Comment: So that I don't misunderstand your notation would you please give a small example of the input and output that you desire?

Comment: Ok, let's say OldList = {a,b,c}. I want to construct a new list as   NewList = { $$ \frac{1}{\lvert a-b \rvert ^2}+ \frac{1}{\lvert a-c \rvert ^2}, \frac{1}{\lvert b-a \rvert ^2}+\frac{1}{\lvert b-c \rvert ^ 2}, \frac{1}{\lvert c-a \rvert ^2}+\frac{1}{\lvert c-b \rvert ^2}  $$ }

Comment: Worth to point out that there probably should be no duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

### Literal methods

First way I thought of:

```
f1 = Table[Total[1/Abs[#[[i]] - Delete[#, i]]^2], {i, Length@#}] &;

f1[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1/Abs[a - b]^2 + 1/Abs[a - c]^2,
>  1/Abs[-a + b]^2 + 1/Abs[b - c]^2, 
>  1/Abs[-a + c]^2 + 1/Abs[-b + c]^2}
> ```

Or using `MapIndexed` as rasher did, but using the listability of all operations:

```
f2[old_List] := MapIndexed[Total[1/(Abs[# - Drop[old, #2]]^2)] &, old]

f2[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1/Abs[a - b]^2 + 1/Abs[a - c]^2,
>  1/Abs[-a + b]^2 + 1/Abs[b - c]^2, 
>  1/Abs[-a + c]^2 + 1/Abs[-b + c]^2}
> ```

See **Case #4** in [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica/7925#7925).

Note: you can use [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tr.html) in place of [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Total.html) for vector sums; it is slightly faster on packed arrays, and syntactically shorter which I like.  However it gives the trace of a matrix (of course) rather than a sum, so I did not use it here just in case your list elements are themselves lists.

### Matrix method

Unlike the methods above that [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Delete.html) or [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Drop.html) the unwanted element, we can leave this element, replace the resulting zeros with ones, perform the sum, and then remove the ones again.

```
f3[old_List] :=
  With[{diag = IdentityMatrix @ Length @ old},
    Total[1/(Abs[# - old & /@ old]^2 + diag), {2}] - 1
  ]

f3[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1/Abs[a - b]^2 + 1/Abs[a - c]^2,
>  1/Abs[-a + b]^2 + 1/Abs[b - c]^2, 
>  1/Abs[-a + c]^2 + 1/Abs[-b + c]^2}
> ```

### Extensions

You asked about a variation of this operation.  Here are examples.

```
g1[old_List] := MapIndexed[# - Drop[old, #2] &, old] // Total[#/Abs[#]^2, {2}] &

g1[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {(a - b)/Abs[a - b]^2 + (a - c)/Abs[a - c]^2,
>  (-a + b)/Abs[-a + b]^2 + (b - c)/Abs[b - c]^2,
>  (-a + c)/Abs[-a + c]^2 + (-b + c)/Abs[-b + c]^2}
> ```

```
g2[old_List] :=
 With[{
   diag = IdentityMatrix @ Length @ old,
   sub = # - old & /@ old
  },
  Total[sub/(Abs[sub]^2 + diag), {2}]
 ]

g2[{a, b, c}] === g1[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

### Timings

Here are timings of each of these methods performed in *Mathematica* 7.  I had hoped that the matrix method (`f3`) would be faster, but at least in the extended example it is faster than the alternative.  (This test uses over 1GB of RAM.)

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

big = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, 5000];

timeAvg[#@big] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
```

> ```
> {0.405, 0.39, 0.437}
> ```

```
timeAvg[#@big] & /@ {g1, g2}
```

> ```
> {1.201, 0.484}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm newbie to Mathematica, so can you explain the reasoning a bit? one more question : If I want to make elements of the new list as $ NewList[index] = \sum_{index \neq j}^{NumOfElts} \frac {OldList[index]-Oldlist[j]}{ \lvert OldList[index]-OldList[j] \rvert ^2 } $ how do I do it according to this logic?

Comment: +1 for the usual beautification of code!

Comment: @christian Complete.

Answer (score 3):

```
oldlist = {a, b, c}

Total /@ MapIndexed[
  Map[Function[arg, 1/(Abs[arg - #]^2)], Drop[oldlist, #2]] &, 
  oldlist]

(*  {1/Abs[-a + b]^2 + 1/Abs[-a + c]^2, 1/Abs[a - b]^2 + 1/Abs[-b + c]^2, 
 1/Abs[a - c]^2 + 1/Abs[b - c]^2} *)
```

Comment: +1 for `MapIndexed`, which is cleaner than `Table`, but there is no need for the inner `Function`; please see my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: yep - I'm always forgetting listability, you'd think from my Lisp days it would be burned in...as an aside, the `@` to reply does not seem to always work, is there some site issue?

Comment: What about the `@` notification system isn't working?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'd say about 30% of the time, when I type the @, it does not fill in the name, and even if I explicitly fill out the whole name, comment shows up with no reference. Tried on three different browsers, so *fairly* sure it's not on my end. No big deal, just makes me feel sloppy.

Comment: I am guessing you are attempting to notify the author of the post under which your are commenting; that author is *automatically* notified, so the `@` isn't necessary, and in fact the system strips it out.

Comment: Also no need to `Map` onto `Total`. Use level spec {2} with `Total`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little convoluted and  not efficient (...it has been a long day...):

```
fun[u_] := Module[{len, arg},
  len = Length[u] - 1;
  arg = RotateLeft[u, #] & /@ Range[0, len];
  Map[Function[s, 
    Total@Map[Function[x, 1/Abs[#1 - x]^2], {##2}] & @@ s], arg]]
```

Testing:

```
fun[{a, b, c}]
```

gives:

> {1/Abs[a - b]^2 + 1/Abs[a - c]^2, 1/Abs[-a + b]^2 + 1/Abs[b - c]^2,
>   1/Abs[-a + c]^2 + 1/Abs[-b + c]^2}